# Saving logs in file that will be used for analysis

Tags: files, logs

How do I copy realtime logs into a `.txt` file?  That is, I have one server and real time logs going on. Is it possible to save the logs over some time period in a `.txt` file?

Comment: You can use `tail -f /path/to/log/file | tee logs.txt`

Comment: In addition to @Ron's comment, you can do this regularly by making it a script and adding it to a `cron` event at a scheduled time.

Comment: They already _are_ text files? That's exactly was `syslog` does, receive log messages and write them to text files.

Comment: @AlexP I want logs of some 'specific time span' . i.e. if logs are going on and one call is starting from now and it is upto 2 minute . in that case I want that specific logs in text file.

Comment: Use `sed` on the system logs?

Comment: Or, for example, before doing the operation of interest start a `tail -F` redirected to a file on the log of interest, then kill it with Ctrl-C after the operation completes?